# Printing nice menus using template file

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I am having a custom menu created in admin/structure/menu configured to nice-menus. and now I am trying to print that menu using my section.tpl.php file like

```
$nice_menu = block_load('nice_menus',"1");
print drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($nice_menu ))));
```

What I see is only the menu title displaying on the page, when I inspect the html source in firebug I see the html needed for the menus are generated. This is frustrating me for the last couple of hours, is there is another way to print my nice menu using the template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$nice_menus_block =_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array(block_load('nice_menus', '1' /*1,2,3 more,  this is get nice_menus_2 block*/))));
print render($nice_menus_block);
```